# AWK script to combine multiple-field validations

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with 7 columns with caret (^) separator
example

```
ABCD123456^12345678^192.654^02Aug15^12:10:36
```

I wrote an awk command which will check duplicates

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' filename
```

Length of first field should be 10 & second should be 8

```
awk -f '^' '{ if ((length($1) == 10) && (length($1) == 10)) print }'
```

Question is

1. How can I do time validation (`[0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]`)? what awk query

   awk -F '^' '$5 ~ [0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]' print

   But this is not working
2. Date Validation. How can I validate 2 digit day, 3 Char Month &  2 digit year
3. Decimal Number validation in 3rd field
4. How can I combine this all in single awk script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them into one awk command like this:

```
awk -F '^' 'length($1) == 10 && length($2) == 8 &&
     $3 ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/ && $5 ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ && !seen[$0]++' file
```

Comment: Perfect!!, How can I validate 02Aug15, any or just `/^[0-9]{2}[A-S][a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}$/`

Comment: Yes `/^[0-9]{2}[A-S][a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}$/` should work fine.

Comment: Works As a Charm, +1 for efficient way to do this